# TableNotFoundException EzPlatform

Tags: symfony, doctrine, ezplatform

I just started a new project with *ezlunachpad* and I'm facing `TableNotFoundException` it mean there's no table in my database.
Already tried `docker:importdata` command, but didn't solve my issue.

This is my Exception trace:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ TableNotFoundException
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t.* FROM
>   ezcontentobject_tree t WHERE t.node_id = ?' with params [2]:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'ezplatform.ezcontentobject_tree' doesn't exist Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\
>   PDOException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'ezplatform.ezcontentobject_tree' doesn't exist

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you have your docker containers up, you can always enter the engine one and try the isntall process from there.

it could be something like

```
~/ez enter engine
```

and in the container

```
./bin/console ezplatform:install clean
```

that will populate all the tables needed by ez to work.

Comment: The configured database 'ezplatform' does not exist or cannot be created.

Comment: which ezplatform version are you using? ezplatform:install should create the database itself. in fact, how did you started your  ez Stack?

Comment: In fact i'm facing this roblem right now `[web/ | web/var] is not writable`

Comment: that web | web var is inside container or the host?

Comment: outside. I's in my local machine

Comment: quick fix, you can try chmod -R 777 to web... i don't know why are you having those kind of problems though. i use ezlaunchpad a lot and i don't have these kind of issues, sorry...